# Two tests are used to determine if a patient is sick...

Tags: probability

**Test one when patient is sick:**
        Positive $80\%$ of cases
        Negative in $20\%$ of cases

**Test one when patient is not sick:**
 
        False-Positive in $30\%$ of cases
        Negative in $70\%$ of cases

**Test two when patient is sick:**
        Test is positive $80\%$ of cases
        Test is negative in $20\%$ of cases

**Test two when patient is not sick:**
        Test is false-positive in $20\%$ of cases
        Test is negative in $80\%$ of cases

It it known that $50\%$ of people are sick...

Among the sick patients $10\%$ are tested negative by test 1 and positive by test 2

Among the non-sick patients $10$ are tested negative by test 1 and positive by test 2

A new patient is tested by both tests...
Test 1 shows Positive
Test 2 shows Negative

Find the posterior probability the patient is sick..

BEFORE I can even solve this problem I need to figure out what posterior probability is in this context?

Any direction is highly appreciated

Comment: For the non-sick patients, did you mean $10$ or $10\%$?  Also, please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The posterior probability is the probability that the hypothesis is true given relevant observations (tests).

In this case, calculate the probability that the patient is sick given Test 1 is positive and Test 2 is negative.

Comment: so I don't really understand how to incorporate the it is known that 50% of people are sick, Among the sick patients 10% are tested negative by test 1 and positive by test 2, Among the non-sick patients 10 are tested negative by test 1 and positive by test 2

Comment: I think I see bayes theorem in here

Comment: so something like P(Patient is sick | Test 1 is positive and Test 2 is negative) = (P(Test 1 is positive and Test 2 is negative | Patient is sick ) * P(patient is sick)) / P(Test 1 is positive and Test 2 is negative)